# Move a matrix to the top right corner using pdfbox

Tags: java, matrix, pdfbox

**Context :**

I'm fairly new generating pdf and i'm scaling a matrix but my issue is that when the matrix gets scaled it then put my scaled matrix to the bottom left corner of the pdf.

**My issue :**

My problem is that actually when i cale my pdf it get stuck at the bottom left corner of the page and i can't find a way to put it on the top right corner whatever of the size of the scaled matrix.

**My code :**

```
float titleWidth = font.getStringWidth(title) / 1000 * fontSize;
float titleHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;
float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
float height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
float ratio = Math.min(maxWidth/width, maxHeight /height);
float scaledWidth = width * ratio;
float scaledHeight = height * ratio;
page.setCropBox(PDRectangle.A4);

matrix.scale(sx = width / scaledWidth, height / scaledHeight);
contentStream.transform(matrix);

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(((page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - titleWidth) / 2), page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - marginTop - titleHeight);
contentStream.setFont(font, (float) (fontSize));
contentStream.showText(title);
contentStream.endText();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

contentStream.close();
document.save(os);
document.close();

return  os.toByteArray();
```

This is a screenshoot of were the scaled matrix actually is (in case my explanation are not clean) :

[image]

Comment: Translate to page height minus height of your image because y 0 is at bottom.

Comment: i alredy tried that but strangely my matrix do not move all to the top, t rest like in the middle of the page

Comment: Add you first scale the coordinate system and then translate it, the translation is subject to the scaling. Thus, you have to use inversely scaled values for the translation. E.g. if the initial scaling is by .5, you have to double the translation values determined from unscaled data.

Comment: i don't really understand you explanation, can you please geave me a formula that do what you are meaning ?

Comment: Divide the newLineAtOffset values by the scale.